# Download PDF using Selenium in Python + save each PDF with an assigned name

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, web-scraping

The aim is to 1) scrape a bunch of PDFs for a bunch of companies 2) save them with the corresponding company names, all from https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/appyearlyindex.html?lang=en&board=mainBoard .

My code works for downloading the PDFs, but while the snippet responsible for autodownload is convenient:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "/Users/XXX/Downloads", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
```

I still need to save each PDF using the name of each corresponding company and not just a random PDF file name. The company names can be scraped using:

```
all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='applicant-name']")
```

But how do modify the full code below to **include a loop that saves each PDF file with each company name (and not a random filename)**?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "/Users/XXX/Downloads", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})

year = str(input("Please enter the year for which you want to download the Application Proofs: "))
link = "https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/appyearlyindex.html?lang=en&board=mainBoard&year=" + year
print("Now loading: ", link)
print("Found the following companies: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get(link)

all_proofs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='record-ap-phip']//a[contains(.,'Full Version')]")
all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='applicant-name']")

for i in all_names:
    print('---> ', i.text)

print("\nTotal number of proofs in year ",year,": ",len(all_proofs))
Y = 0
N = 0
for proof in all_proofs:
    try:
        proof.click()
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='warning-statement-dialog']//label[@for='warning-statement-accept']"))).click()
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='warning-statement-dialog']//a[contains(@class,'btn-ok')]"))).click()
        Y += 1
    except Exception as exc:
        exception = f'An exception occurred.'
        N += 1

print("Number of application proofs downloaded: ", Y)
print("Number of exceptions: ", N)
```

Comment: You could do without Selenium if you query the [api calls](https://www1.hkexnews.hk/ncms/json/eds/app_2021_sehk_e.json) directly (change the year in the url for a different year). You'll find the company name and direct pdf link in the json

Answer (score 1):

As RJ Adriaansen pointed out there is a JSON file in the Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR that can easily be scraped without Selenium:

```
import requests
import re

for year in range(2015,2023):

    data_url = f'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/ncms/json/eds/app_{str(year)}_sehk_e.json?_=1641899494829' #found in the Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR
    data = requests.get(data_url).json()

    for company in data['app']:
        filename = re.sub(r'[^\w\-_ ]', '_',company['a'])+'.pdf' #company name remove bad characters for filename
        try:
            pdf_url = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/'+company['ls'][0]['u1']

        except:
            continue

        pdf_data = requests.get(pdf_url)

        print(f'Saving {filename}')
        with open(filename,'wb') as file:
            file.write(pdf_data.content)
```

Comment: This works, however I need to be able to get those PDFs from different years, not just 2022 - for example 2021 or 2015, 2011 etc. When I modify your code to include: 

data_url = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/ncms/json/eds/app_' + year + '_sehk_e.json?_=1641899494829' #found in the Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR`

and input `year` as 2021, I get this error:

`File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX/05. AP Analysis/AP Proofs/AP Analysis_PDF_downloader 2.py", line 12, in <module>
    pdf_url = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/'+company['ls'][0]['u1']
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I've edited the script to handle all those years

Comment: Some of the listings don't have the pdf you are looking for, in which case my script will skip them

Comment: Thank you for trying, however the code only downloads a bunch of PDFs that are 2KBs in size each and cannot be opened...is there any way to fix this code so that it will download full PDFs?

Comment: @childnik pdf files downloaded like this wont open in Acrobat Reader. Throws an error: "it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged ". is there some flag that i have to set?